# Json output into single line

Tags: c++, json, boost

Question:

With below sample code, able to create a json string and print as below, my requirements is to print into a single line(below as well) with no space or tab, can i do it using boost or need to explicitly remove from string.

```
#include "boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp"
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

    int main()
    {
            boost::property_tree::ptree root;
            root.put("sessionId", "123456");
            root.put("applicationName", "Sample_Appliation");
            root.put("applicationId", "null");
            root.put("logMessage", "Sample Message");
            root.put("loggingTime", "2020-03-17T13:26:45.013");
            std::stringstream ss;
            boost::property_tree::write_json(ss, root);
            std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;
            return 0;
    }
```

Output:

```
{
    "sessionId": "123456",
    "applicationName": "Sample_Appliation",
    "applicationId": "null",
    "logMessage": "Sample Message",
    "loggingTime": "2020-03-17T13:26:45.013"
}
```

Expected:

```
{"sessionId": "123456","applicationName": "Sample_Appliation","applicationId": "null","logMessage": "Sample Message","loggingTime": "2020-03-17T13:26:45.013"}
```

Comment: With `boost::property_tree::write_json(ss, root, false);` output is oneline.

Answer (score 2):

There is a third parameter to  `boost::property_tree::write_json` named `pretty` with default value `true`, just pass `false` as a third parameter to disable pretty printing.

Answer (score 1):

Big caution: Boost PropertyTree [Is Not A JSON Library](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bboost%5D+ptree+%22not+a+JSON%22). However, as luck would have it, Boost has recently adopted the new [JSON library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/json/doc/html/json/overview.html), which actually does the job:

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/aKzc43)**

```
#include <boost/json.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    auto json = boost::json::parse(R"(
        {
            "sessionId": "123456",
            "applicationName": "Sample_Appliation",
            "applicationId": "null",
            "logMessage": "Sample Message",
            "loggingTime": "2020-03-17T13:26:45.013"
        })");

    std::cout << json;
}
```

Prints

```
{"sessionId":"123456","applicationName":"Sample_Appliation","applicationId":"null","logMessage":"Sample Message","loggingTime":"2020-03-17T13:26:45.013"}
```